# RAID 1 with different disk sizes

Tags: 18.04, raid

I am looking at a new HP desktop pc that comes with a 250 gig SSD and a 2TB HDD.  I would like to install RAID 1 using the SSD and 250 gig of the HDD, then use the remaining 1.75 gig of the HDD for other storage of relatively static data outside of the RAID array.

Is this possible now with 18.04?

Thanks

Pete

Comment: Sure, create a partitions on the 2TB drive and use the smallest (250GB) for mdadm raid.

Comment: Is that RAID 1 for data storage? If not and if its for root OS filesystem, it is really wrong idea : mirroring a fast SSD with a slow HDD will result on a slow mirror...

Comment: Thanks for that information .  Yes I was intending to mirror the OS file system and use the big partition for data which is largely static and anyway backed up hourly with Duplicity.  Sounds like it can be done but I loose the performance advantage of the SSD.  Useful to know.